# Find files containing a string and execute command

Tags: linux, command-line, find, find-in-files

How do I find files that contain a specific string **and** execute a command on these files?

In my case, I'd like to find all `*.md` files that contain the string

```
^  - HIMS$
```

and stage them with git.

I know I can find files containing the string via this command: `grep -rlnw . -e '  - HIMS'`

I also know that I can execute commands on found files via `find`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.md" -exec git add "{}" \;
```

Lastly, I know that I can use to find `md` files and grep:

```
find . -name '*.md' -exec grep -l '  - HIMS' {} \; -print
```

What I don't know is how I could add `git add` to either of the approaches.

I guess, the third approach, while being the slowest, might be the point to hook in. But I don't know how I append `git add` to it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Note: at first you use `^  - HIMS$`, but later `grep -l '  - HIMS'` (no anchors). My answer uses the latter, adjust it to your actual needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `find` command:

> ```
> find . -name '*.md' -exec grep -l '  - HIMS' {} \; -print
> ```

is redundant in its output. `grep -l` prints the pathnames of files you want, but then `-exec` is also a test in `find`. It succeeds iff the executed utility returns exit status zero. Exit status from `grep` deliberately reflects whether there was a match or not, so the tool can be used in a test like this. If the test succeeds, `-print` is evaluated. It prints the pathname `grep` has just printed.

Examine the output closely and you will see pathnames (lines) in pairs. In each pair the first line is from `grep -l` and the second is from `find -print`.

Now we know `-exec` is a test, we can insert it in your first `find` command. Your first `find` command was:

> ```
> find ./ -type f -name "*.md" -exec git add "{}" \;
> ```

Here `-type f` is a test, `-name "*.md"` is another test; you can add yet another test before `-exec git …`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.md" -exec grep -q '  - HIMS' {} \; -exec git add {} \;
```

I used `-q` (quiet) instead of `-l` because we don't want the pathname from `grep`. For each file that passes preceding tests we want exit status from `grep`. The same mechanism that triggered `-print` in your second `find` command will now trigger the second `-exec`.

The second `-exec` is a test too, but there are no further tests or actions in our `find`, so this aspect is irrelevant in our case. In general `-exec` allows you to build custom tests. If you can write shell code or a script, or a program that tests what you want, then you can use it in `find -exec`. It's a very powerful tool.